# IntelliJ 2016.3 GAE Deploy Java8/7

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I'm new at IntelliJ and I created a new empty project(Google App Engine) and changed the bytecode level to 7, but I get this error in deployment:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: org/eclipse/jetty/apache/jsp/JettyJasperInitializer$1.class in C:\Recursos\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.48\jetty93\jetty-distribution\lib\apache-jsp\org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.14.v20161028-nolog.jar
Unable to update app: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: org/eclipse/jetty/apache/jsp/JettyJasperInitializer$1.class in C:\Recursos\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.48\jetty93\jetty-distribution\lib\apache-jsp\org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.14.v20161028-nolog.jar
```

I found this answer [GAE Deploy Java8/Java7 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276023/gae-deploy-java8-java7-error), but I can't find the ***pom*** file.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem after updating to appengine-java-sdk-1.9.48, and switching to 1.9.46 fixed the problem.

You may download the 1.9.46 at https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.46.zip

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Using the IntelliJ plugin, one can deploy to the flex environment, using the 1.8 JDK, as documented on the IntelliJ IDEA [Google Cloud Tools plugin](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/quickstart-IDEA) documentation page.

Still, to deploy in the app engine standard environment (not flex), one needs to choose the 1.7 version of the JDK, as documented on the "Setting up IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition for Java Development and Debugging of App Engine Standard Environment Apps" [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/setting-up-intellij): “The Java SDK should be set to Java 7.”