# Google app engine deployment error: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and following [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/getting-started-with-google-app-engine.html#before_start) tutorial to Deploy an example hello world App. When following the steps to deploy the app I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7
>   org/eclipse/jetty/apache/jsp/JuliLog.class in /Users/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.50/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.16.v20170120-nolog.jar
>
> Unable to update app: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: org/eclipse/jetty/apache/jsp/JuliLog.class in /Users/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.50/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.16.v20170120-nolog.jar

I am using java version 1.7.0_71 in the project structure.
My compiler settings are set to generate 1.7 compatible bytecode:
[image: screenshot of IDE compiler settings]

Anyone have any ideas as to how this can be fixed?

EDIT
Fixed the web.xml version was the problem
[see here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1230)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAE Deploy Java8/Java7 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276023/gae-deploy-java8-java7-error)

Comment: In maven settings within intllij I have set the JDK for importer to 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this report](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/1365#issuecomment-278621916), the problem is caused by `web.xml` version.

> So the problem is that the web.xml uses version 3.1, while App Engine
>   Standard only supports 2.5 which causes the staging to fail with this
>   error message. Please change the version and try deploying again.

Similar problem was [also reported here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1230#issuecomment-278646086).

> you're seeing an open bug we have right now with the App Engine SDK
>   where a misleading error message is provided when you use a Java 7 app
>   with a web.xml configured to servlet 3.1 (which doesn't support Java
>   7).

Comment: in my project web.xml version in 2.5 already, still having this issue. please help, please note i am using Eclipse Neon.

Comment: You might need to specify <runtime>java8</runtime> in appengine-web.xml as specified [there](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `<appengine-web-xml>` tag rather than `<web-xml>` tag, adding `<runtime>java8</runtime>` solved this issue for me (I am using the gradle appengine plugin version 2.0.6).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>my_app_id</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This solved it](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1230#issuecomment-278646086)
Changed the web.xml file to:

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="2.5"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Thank you.